# Cannot connect to Google RDP Virtual Machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have just created a Virtual Machine instance on GCP; I have a username, a password and a ip address.
I opened Remmina on my pc and I tried to connect.
Everything worked for 10 minutes then the screen turned black and I restarted it and, since then, connection doesn't work anymore. I get the "Lost connection" error.
I opened my terminal and I typed telnet 34.xx.xxx.xx and it hangs so I guess that the connection isn't working anymore.

I don't know why since I didn't touch anything.
I also tried to restart the machine and create a new instance but I get the same error.

Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, cannot be sure unless I have seen the gcp account but here are my few guesses :

- Was the account that you created a temperory account ( qwicklabs etc ) that could have expired ?
- Did you change the OS to Core where the login is command prompt based black screen ?

I have just tried to login to the below configuration
[image]

To check if I was able to RDP sucessfully
[image]

Edit 1:
first try to telnet on the port 3389

```
telnet <ip-address> 3389
```

if you are not able to connect try to enable the firewall for 3389

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-rdp --allow tcp:3389
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-rdp) is the Google page for troubleshooting RDP connections

Comment: No, I have just created a new instance, and still not working.
It has exactly the same properties of yours.

Comment: I don't know if you need to see anything in particolar, just tell me

Comment: Can you please add which image are you using , also are you sure your RDP sofware "Remmina" is working approriately ? May be try an alternative ?

Comment: I am not sure about Remmina because I've never used it before. But I also tried to "telnet <ip-address>" on my terminal and still get the same result. About the image, can you tell me how do I find this information?

Comment: Please see the Edits in the answer